# How can i import 6 csv files from one directory in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I tried this code

```
fileList <- list.files(pattern=".csv")

df=sapply(fileList, read.csv)

View(df[[2]])
```

The 6 files name are 
1521211800.csv

1521212400.csv

1521213000.csv

1521213600.csv

1521214200.csv

1521214800.csv

How can I import them and access each of them separately?

Comment: This should be migrated to stack overflow and is likely a duplicate there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Choose the folder containing your csv files:

```
path<-file.choose()
```

Save csv list files

```
fileList <- list.files(path=path,pattern=".csv")
```

Read all csv files

```
df=lapply(paste(path,fileList,sep="/"), read.csv)
```

Your output will have a list of dataframe corresponding to each csv loaded:

```
df
[[1]]
  a b c
1 1 1 1

[[2]]
  a b c
1 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

first set your working directory, where all your files are stored there:

```
setwd("C:/Users/...") 

# then

file.List = list.files(pattern = "*.csv", recursive = F)

for (i in 1:length(file.List)) {

# open the files
input <- read.csv(file.List[i])

# assign a name 
assign(paste("df", (file.List[[i]])), input )

}
```